# Fuzzy maps with QGIS/GRASSGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, terrset

How to do fuzzy maps (FUZZY module in IDRISI) with QGIS/GRASSGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GRASS GIS has:

- [r.fuzzy](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/addons/r.fuzzy.html): Cluster raster maps using fuzzy logic.

In addition GRASS GIS 7.x has

- [r.fuzzy.system](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.fuzzy.system.html)  Full fuzzy logic standalone classification system with few fuzzy logic families implication and defuzzification and methods

Look at [Application of GRASS fuzzy modeling system: estimation of prone risk in Arno River Area (pdf)](http://geoinformatics.fsv.cvut.cz/data/2011/05-20/10-dileo.pdf), for example.

I do not know anything about fuzzy with QGIS only

Answer (score 3):

Since the release of QGIS 3.12 you can do raster value fuzzification (Fuzzy Membership in ArcGIS terms) with the newly added `Fuzzify raster` algorithms in the processing toolbox. Up to date there are the following functions available:

- `Linear Membership`
- `Power Membership`
- `Fuzzy-Small Membership`
- `Fuzzy-Large Membership`
- `Fuzzy-Near Membership`
- `Gaussian Membership`

You can have a look at the [information included in the pull request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/32701) on Github for more information on the functions.